# How do I sync contacts between 2 iCloud accounts?

Tags: icloud, contacts

I need to sync my contact list with my husband's phone. We both have our own iCloud accounts.

Comment: on your husband's phone go to Settings -> Mail -> Add an account then choose sync contacts

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, iCloud will not do this between two separate iCloud accounts. You can pursue one of the following two options:

#### Option 1

1. Create an additional AppleID for contact/calendar sync only. Add
   that account to your devices but don't sign in yet.
2. You will not be able to use your own AppleID and the additional
   AppleID you just created concurrently.
3. On each persons computer, drag your contacts to your desktop to
   create vcard files. Log out of the personal account.
4. Login to the 3rd AppleID (shared).
5. Drag the vcard files into the Contacts.app which will add them to
   the app. Repeat this process on any additioanal computer that wants
   to share the list. This is the contact (and calendar) you will use
   going forward. You can still keep a private contact list under your
   original AppleID but you will need to logout and back into that ID
   when you want to access the private contacts.
6. Once you are done remove the duplicates or merge the contacts and
   any private contacts you don't want in the list. There are several
   additional apps that will do this for you. Just do a search on the
   internet for one that suits you.

#### Option 2

Setup a Google account that you both use for contacts and sync with that. This method is not optimal because in either scenario you will end up with all contacts included in the set and because there's always a chance that some future update to googles apps this method may cause problems in the future.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: option 3 is to set up our own contacts server, like with the unfortunately no longer supported Server.app or OwnCloud, NextCloud etc.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this as a one time thing, is to open Contacts.app on a Mac that is set up on your iCloud account. Select all contacts and drag them to the desktop. That will export them all as a .vcard file.

Then move the file to another account on a Mac set up with your husband's iCloud account. Open Contacts.app, and drag the .vcard file into the app.

That will get all of your contacts into his account. But this will be a one time thing, and you may get some duplicates.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question how to sync contacts.

Answer (score -1):

A manual syncing procedure is described in the [support forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8370690):

> However, you can easily put existing Contacts on a new Apple ID. On an iOS device where you have the original Apple ID signed in, you can sign that ID out of iCloud. When it asks if you want to keep your Contacts on the device, say Yes. Then sign in the other Apple ID. When it asks if you want to merge the Contacts on the device to the iCloud account being signed in, say Merge.

And once you've done this:

> Going forward, it is quite simple to select new cards and email them to other Apple IDs. You would select the new Contact, click on the Share button, and email it to whomever you wish. When they receive it on an Apple device or computer, they can double-click the card, and it asks if they want to add it to their Contacts.